# Problema al cambiar a Modo Oscuro (Dark Mode) en proyecto Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Os comento mi problema.

Estoy creando una aplicación básica donde aparece un layout con un BottomNavigationView y sus respectivos fragments. Hasta aquí todo bien, me compila y funciona.

El problema está cuando selecciono el modo oscuro desde el menú del móvil. Tengo un Xiaomi Mi. Cuando lo selecciono, al seleccionar otro tab, solo me aparece el que tenía visualizado. Es como si eliminara o dejará de cargar los fragments.

Os paso el código.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

private var homeRouter : HomeRouter? = null
private var dashboardRouter : DashboardRouter? = null
private var notificationsRouter : NotificationsRouter? = null
private var selectedItem: Int = -1

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    // Content
    setContentView(binding.root)

    // ViewModel
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[MainViewModel::class.java]

    // Setup
    setup()
}

private fun setup(){
    loadFragments()
    defaultFragment()
}

private fun loadFragments(){

    // Fragments
    homeRouter?.remove(supportFragmentManager)
    dashboardRouter?.remove(supportFragmentManager)
    notificationsRouter?.remove(supportFragmentManager)

    homeRouter = HomeRouter()
    dashboardRouter = DashboardRouter()
    notificationsRouter = NotificationsRouter()

    binding.navView.setOnItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
        if (selectedItem != menuItem.itemId){
            selectedItem = menuItem.itemId
            when(menuItem.itemId){
                R.id.navigation_home -> {
                    dashboardRouter?.hide(supportFragmentManager)
                    notificationsRouter?.hide(supportFragmentManager)
                    if (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(R.id.navigation_home.toString()) == null){
                        homeRouter?.add(supportFragmentManager,
                            R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main, R.id.navigation_home.toString())
                    }
                    homeRouter?.show(supportFragmentManager)
                }
                R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
                    homeRouter?.hide(supportFragmentManager)
                    notificationsRouter?.hide(supportFragmentManager)
                    if (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(R.id.navigation_dashboard.toString()) == null){
                        dashboardRouter?.add(supportFragmentManager,
                            R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main, R.id.navigation_dashboard.toString())
                    }
                    dashboardRouter?.show(supportFragmentManager)
                }
                R.id.navigation_notifications -> {
                    homeRouter?.hide(supportFragmentManager)
                    dashboardRouter?.hide(supportFragmentManager)
                    if (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(R.id.navigation_notifications.toString()) == null){
                        notificationsRouter?.add(supportFragmentManager,
                            R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main, R.id.navigation_notifications.toString())
                    }
                    notificationsRouter?.show(supportFragmentManager)
                }
            }
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
}

private fun defaultFragment(){
    binding.navView.selectedItemId = viewModel.defaultFragment()
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(false)
}
}
```

Interface

```
interface BaseActivityRouter {
// Activity
fun intent(activity: Context): Intent
fun launch(activity: Context) = activity.startActivity(intent(activity))
}

interface BaseFragmentRouter {

// Fragment

fun fragment() : Fragment

fun add(manager: FragmentManager, containerId: Int, tag: String) = manager.beginTransaction().add(containerId, fragment(), tag).commitAllowingStateLoss()

fun replace(manager: FragmentManager, containerId: Int) = manager.beginTransaction().replace(containerId, fragment()).commit()

fun show(manager: FragmentManager) = manager.beginTransaction().show(fragment()).commitAllowingStateLoss()

fun hide(manager: FragmentManager) = manager.beginTransaction().hide(fragment()).commitAllowingStateLoss()

fun remove(manager: FragmentManager) = manager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment()).commitAllowingStateLoss()
}
```

Si necesitáis algo mas no dudéis en pedirlo.

El código está en mi repositorio de github https://github.com/TitoDevs/BottomNavigationView

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Ya solucioné el problema. Tenía que añadir a AndroidManifest la siguiente línea en el activity principal (que es donde me daba problemas)

android:configChanges="uiMode"

Que en este caso quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
 <activity
     android:name=".usecases.main.MainActivity"
     android:exported="true"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     android:configChanges="uiMode"
     tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```